# call api and render data after states get updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In use effect I am checking current role of user, if it is admin `setAdmin(true)` set the state of admin. The default admin state is false. When component gets rendered, it gets rendered with admin as false and state gets updated in sometime. I want to call api and render data after state gets updated.

```
useEffect(async () => {
    //Authenticates User through their email
    let firebaseId;
    const user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
      let getUserProfile = async () => {
        let loggedInUser = await axios.get(
          `${config.API_URL}/data/profile/${user.uid}`
        );
        if (loggedInUser.data.role == "admin") {
          setAdmin(true);
        }
      };
      getUserProfile();
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect hook in above case.

Ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Call your API
}, [admin]);
```

Above hook will call when `admin` state updated.

Comment: it works but still for some minor seconds data is rendered for default admin state